# Convergence of $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{2k+1}{10k+2} \sin(\frac{k\pi}{2}) $

Tags: calculus, absolute-convergence

Task is to determine if the infinite sum converges absolutely, conditionally or doesn't converge.

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{2k+1}{10k+2} \sin\left(\frac{k\pi}{2}\right)$$

I have determined that values $a_{n=2k}$ result as $0$, so this equation can be written as.

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \left|\frac{2k+1}{10k+2} \sin\left(\frac{k\pi}{2}\right)\right| =\sum_{k=2n+1}^{\infty} \frac{2k+1}{10k+2}=$$  $$\{k,n\} \in \Bbb{N}  $$

$$=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{4n+3}{20n+3} $$
and this doesn't converge if I test it this way:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{4n+3}{20n+3} \div \frac{1}{n^\alpha} $$

so I test to see if it converges conditionally
$$ |a_{n}| > |a_{n+1}| $$ $$ n \in \Bbb{R} $$
and
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{4n+3}{20n+3} = \frac{1}{5}  $$

thus I conclude that the sum converges conditionally, am I right?

EDIT:

The necessary condition $$\lim_{n\to\infty} |a_n| = 0 $$ hasn't been met, thus the sum doesn't converge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Show that the terms do not have limit $0$. Recall that **if** $\sum a_n$ converges, **then** $\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n=0$. (The converse does not hold.)

Comment: oh! yes. the necessary condition. Thus the sum doesn't converge. Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome. The simplest divergence test!